# Unable to connect to SQL Server on AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I created a new SQL Server Express with 'admin' username & password.

I added inbound rules in Security Groups to allow all traffic from my laptop's IP address & default gateway (Do I need to do both Ipv4 address & also the gateway for connectivity to go thru?)

When I tried to connect to the newly created SQL Server via SSMS using SQL Server authentication with username `admin` & password that I used while creating the Instance. The connection fails with the error message below. What am I doing wrong?

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to sql-xxxxxxxxxxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com.
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

Answer (score 0):

1. **Check Public access for RDS Instance**: You are trying to access the RDS instance from your laptop - means trying to access RDS from outside VPC that is hosting the instance. In that case you must enable public access to the RDS instance. This would assign a public IP. You can modify this feature after creating the RDS instance too.
2. **Security Group rules**: Port 1433 must be opened for the IP address you would like to access from - your home/work IP address. You can select 'My IP' on source when creating Security Group rules, this will set your IP automatically as source.

PS: Please make sure the subnet where RDS instance is hosted does not have any blocks at NACL level and subnet's route table has route to internet traffic, through Internet Gateway.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there a way to enable access from specific IPs (outside VPC) for dbs that are in VPC without enabling public access?

Comment: I have added 'My IP' in the Security Group rules. But, that didn't help. I noticed that the IP 'My IP' feature populates is different from what I get when I do IP config. My IP detects my laptop's IP as 76.x.x.x while ipconfig shows up my IP as 192.x.x.x. This is very confusing to me.

Comment: 192.x.x.x is your local IP address and 76.x.x.x is your public one. Your machine is available to the external world with public address only. Instances inside a VPC without public address can not be accessed from outside - this is how it is built, only devices inside VPC can access them(for security reasons).